# Will Windows run slowly if in a VM?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

so I was thinking about switching my main OS to Ubuntu so I could get my foot in the door with linux and start experimenting around with it a bunch. However, I know if I do that a lot of games will be unavailable to me because they require Windows. That being said, I was thinking about making a Windows VM on the Ubuntu OS and using that to play games on it.

I have a few questions about this.

Will I be able to play games like Siege with the same FPS as right now (not using a VM and Windows as main OS)? If not, is there a way to go about getting more FPS in those games? If so, is there a tutorial for it (because I don't know anything advanced and if there isn't a tutorial I don't think I'll be able to do it).

Will the Windows VM boot slowly (on same SSD as main host Ubuntu)?

Is there anything I won't be able to do on a Windows VM that I would be able to do if my main OS was windows (I.E any important features or apps I'll be forced to miss out on)?

If I run a game on the Windows VM (while ubuntu is the host machine), will I still be able to play all windows games? Will I get the same performance or something close to it?

Lastly, bit of a specific question. But since Visual Studio is only on Windows, I will have to use the Windows VM to use Visual Studio. Will the performance of Visual Studio be impacted? (Not Visual Studio CODE. I know that's on Linux)

(For some reason it's asking me to make sure I've included my windows version, even though it's irrelevant to the question, I'll include it) : Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042

Thanks in advance for any info! Sorry if I'm posting this in the wrong spot or anything, but I think I posted it in the right spot.

P.S My PC info is as follows:

Case: Vanguard-RGB Black ATX Mid Tower Gaming Computer Case w/Tempered Glass
Power Supply: EVGA SuperNOVA 850 G+ 80 Plus Gold 850W Fully Modular
Motherboard: ASUS TUF Z390-Pro Gaming (WIFI) LGA 1151
CPU: Intel i5-9600k @ 4.6GHz
CPU Cooler: Hyper 212 RGB Black Edition
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070
RAM: 4x16GB DDR4 @ 3200MHz (Corsair Vengeance Pro RGB)
Disk 0: 1TB M.2 SSD (WDC WDS100T2B0B-00YS70)
Disk 1: 2TB HDD (ST2000DM001-1ER164)
Disk 2: 1TB TOSHIBA MQ02ABD100H
Disk 3: External Backup 4TB (Seagate Backup+ Hub BK SCSI)
Keyboard: ROCCAT VULCAN 122 AIMO
Mouse: ROCCAT Kone AIMO Wired Optical Gaming Mouse
Monitor 1: Alienware AW2518H 1920x1440 @ 240Hz
Monitor 2: Alienware AW2518H 1920x1440 @ 240Hz

Comment: The fancy unicode bold text hurts the readability of your question, putting emphasis on the part that's not that important at all. You may want to [edit] it out.

Comment: Also, let's talk about the elephant in the room: why not just run Linux in a VM?

Comment: I want to use linux as my main OS because it's more lightweight and definitely spies on me less than something like Windows, will boot faster, less viruses are geared towards linux, and I dont like running windows outside of a vm because if it gets infected I want to toss it away not reinstall my entire OS.

Comment: "Switch... my main OS to Ubuntu so I could get my foot in the door with linux"   <-- Use Linux of choice as a VM. I have two of these (Ubuntu and Kali) and they both work well. That leaves my Windows Host intact. It starts fast (as fast as my Linux VMs) so nothing lost there.  Windows with built-in security is also safe. This has been working well for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

When you run any kind of virtualization, it will always be slower than running it natively because there are additional layer involved (hypervisor). The question is, how much slower and how much would it impact your usability? Usually, graphic related tasks have the largest impact, especially 3D graphics (gaming). So you definitely won't have the same FPS if you run games in VM. As for other applications, it will be slower, but the performance penalty is probably not significant enough to impact your usability. You'll just have to try to get the exact answer, because different apps behave differently and usability is subjective from one person to another (e.g. I might be OK with waiting extra 0.2 second delay when clicking a button, but you might not be OK with it) Generally, you should be fine with none graphic intensive application. But for gaming in VM, highly not recommended.

For your case, there are a few approach

1. You could dual boot Linux and Windows, use Linux as your daily driver and switch to Windows when you want to game
2. Since you have 64GB of RAM, you can run Windows natively, and use this only for gaming, then have Linux on VM and use it as your daily driver. You can also have another Windows VM for experimenting so that if you're infected, you can just reload the VM snapshot.

Comment: Gaming with native-like performance would be possible with hardware passthrough (if you can get it to work), but that would require separate GPUs for host and guest.